# How to get the disk size of portable disks?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
block_devices=client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].getBlockDevices(id=id)
```

This API call doesn't tell what is the size of the disks.

Is there any other way to get the disk size of a portable storage for a particular Virtual Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
objectMask='mask[capacity, name, id, description]'
objectFilter ={"portableStorageVolumes":{"blockDevices":{"guest":{"id":{"operation":VirtualGuestID}}}}}

result = client['Account'].getPortableStorageVolumes(filter=objectFilter, mask=objectMask)
```

Replace the VirtualGuestID with the ID of your virtual guest, the objectfilter will return all the portable storages that your VSI has and the objectMask will display their capacity for those stoages